# Windows batch file - How to shuffle and unshuffle files using variable inputs

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

**EDIT:** Updated to be more clear and to clarify that I only want to shuffle files 001 to 049 and leave file 050 as 050 and added an "Ideal End Goal Concept" at the end of this post

I'm looking for a way to shuffle 49 files in the current directory with my Windows batch file. All of the files are named .001, .002, etc. all the way to .049 using 9 or 10 numbers entered as variables to the batch file.  I need to be able to use the same 9 or 10 numbers entered as variables to be able to "unshuffle" the files back to their original state using a seperate batch file.  Any ideas and code examples to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my batch file command line example:

I have 50 files in the folder named testfile.exe.001 to .050 (I only want to shuffle 001 - 049)

```
shuffle.bat testfile.exe 8 5 2 9 4 1 3 7 6
```

Making sure that I don't use the same number twice and not in the same place (i.e. don't put "1" as the first variable or it will just rename .001 to .001) so that the first 9 files are shuffled.

I then do something like this:

```
rem temporarily renaming .001 - .050 files to .001a - .050a to prevent collisions
ren %1.0?? %1.0??a
ren %1.001a %1.00%2
rem which renames testfile.exe.001a to testfile.exe.008
ren %1.002a %1.00%3
rem which renames testfile.exe.002a to testfile.exe.005
ren %1.003a %1.00%4
rem which renames testfile.exe.003a to testfile.exe.002
rem etc. all the way up to %1.009a
```

Then I figured, I could do the same with files .011 - .019, then with files .021 - 0.29, etc.  and that works, but it doesn't shuffle the files across the entire span of 49 files.  For example .005 could not become .045, etc.

To unshuffle, I would have to enter the same 9 or 10 number variables into the unshuffler batch file which just does everything in reverse.  So without those 9 or 10 numbers (which act as a sequence or 'kind of' password), the files could not be restored to their original names.

Is there a way to improve my code or a better way to shuffle these 50 files using batch file variables (numbers) which would cause a shuffle across the entire span of 49 files and be totally reversible using the same 9 or 10 numbers as variables?  Thanks for any help!

**Ideal End Goal Concept:**

To be able to shuffle these 49 files with all of these being true:

- Ability to input a code on the command line (varible(s)) which uniquely affects and is the key to the shuffling order and allows unshuffling
- Every file's original order has been changed to another order
- No two files from the original order are one after the other in the shuffled order
- All files can be shuffled across the entire 001-049 set (e.g. 005 can become 045, 032 can become 016, etc.)

Comment: Your task is unclear. What do you mean by shuffle? because it looks like you're renaming files. How about you start by providing us with the content of tbe directory, then show your batch file, then show the intended final content of the directory after the first run of the batch file. Next tell us what you want to be able to do after the first run of the batch file, using the same idea. Please do that by using the [edit] button; do not put that information in the comment section.

Comment: Hi Compo.  By "shuffle" I am referring to renaming files in a set of 49 files using command line variables passed to the batch file (9 or 10 numbers) which control the order of the shuffle so that the files can be unshuffled later.  Kind of like a magician who can shuffle a deck of cards in such a way that he still knows how to put them back in the order he wants later. @Aacini has given a good example of the kind of solution I'm looking for.

Comment: How about you run the shuffle, the files are shuffled using the random function, and producing a report line showing the 50 required numbers and then run the unshuffler and need to supply the correct sequence of 50 numbers to get back the original order? Note that if you provide an incorrect combination to the unshuffler, you get the files reshuffled with no guarantee of (no duplicates) or (files disappear) ?

Comment: A good idea @Magoo  This would work (if the random numbers don't repeat and don't coincide with the original file order at any point), however having to enter 50 numbers (or 49 since I want file 50 to remain in place) to unshuffle would be cumbersome.  I would like to be able to enter 10 numbers and derive the shuffling of the whole 49 files from that.  Thanks for your suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sourcedir=c:\testso"

set "filename=%1"
:: clear any variables starting #
for /f "tokens=1delims==" %%e in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%e="

:: number of files
set /a #files=8
set /a #files1k=1000+#files

set "parm= %* "
set /a #count=0
set /a #randomadd=0
call :readparms %parm%

:: if 0 or 1 parameter, shuffle randomly
if %#count% lss 2 goto shuffle

:: unshuffling

echo unshuffling
call :shuffleren
goto :eof


:shuffle
set /a #remain=#files1k
for /L %%e in (1001,1,%#remain%) do set "#%%e="
:another
set /a #choice=((%random%+#randomadd) %% #files) + 1001

if defined #%#choice% goto another
if %#remain%%#choice%==10011001 goto shuffle
if %#choice% equ %#remain% goto another
set /a #%#choice%=%#remain%
if %#remain%==1001 goto doneshuffle
set /a #remain-=1
goto another

:doneshuffle
set "#report="
set #lastnum=0
for /L %%e in (1001,1,%#files1k%) do (
 set /a #num=!#%%e!-1000
 set /a #lastnum+=1
 if !#num!==!#lastnum! goto shuffle
 set /a #lastnum=#num
 set "#report=!#report! !#num!
)
call :shuffleren
echo sequence=%#report:~1%
goto :eof

:shuffleren
for /L %%e in (1001,1,%#files1k%) do (
 set "#oldname=%%e"
 set "#newname=!#%%e!"
 ren "%sourcedir%\%filename%*.!#oldname:~-3!" "%filename%*.!#oldname:~-3!.!#newname:~-3!.t"
)
for %%b in ("%sourcedir%\%filename%*.t") do ren "%%b" "%%~nb"
goto :eof

:readparms
shift
set "parm=%1"
if not defined parm goto :eof
set "parm=9%1"
for /L %%e in (0,1,9) do set "parm=!parm:%%e=!"
if defined parm echo ignored "%1" &goto readparms
set /a #randomadd=%1
set /a parm=1000+%1
set /a #count+=1
set /a #count1k=1000+#count
set /a #%parm%=#count1k

goto readparms
```

We start with setting the directory to examine and read the filename from the parameter list; then clear any variables starting `#`.

Establish the number of files to manipulate - I've seen the revised spec. that this should be 49, not 50. I used 8 for testing.

Calculate 1000+#files to save repeatedly calculating. Initialise the count of numeric parameters found and read the parameters from the command line using `:readparms`. I had some control options to facilitate testing, so added a space either end of the passed parameters list `%*`.

Having read and stored the parameters,examine `#count` - 0 or 1 means to shuffle, more means unshuffle.

So, shuffling :

First, set all variables `#1001` to `#1050` (it's self-adjusting to `#files` specified) to *nothing*.

Next, generate a random number 1001..1050 and if it's not already assigned, assign the remaining number from the range 1001..1050 to `#the randomnumber` and decrement the number remaining until it reaches 1001 (last one assigned). If both `#count` and `#remain` are `1001` then we're attempting to rename `.001` to `.001` so we start again. If `#remain` and `#choice` are the same otherwise, choose another number

When we're done shuffling, we need to build the  unshuffle string. We grab each number in turn from `#1000` to `#1050`, convert it to a natural number (no leading zeroes) and compare it against the last number processed - if the difference is 1, then we're attempting to resequence 2 sequential filenumbers, and that's not allowed - so restart the shuffling.

Finally, we have a set of variables such as

```
#1001=1004
#1002=1003
#1003=1002
#1004=1001
```

which means that file.001 will become .004 ,etc.

So, execute `:shuffleren` to rename the files.

I chose to rename the files by appending an extra 2 extensions (the new name and a `t`) then remove the `t`. This shows a trace of the old and new names (filename.002 becomes filename.002.003 in the above). Changing `"%filename%*.!#oldname:~-3!.!#newname:~-3!.t"` to `"%filename%*.!#newname:~-3!.t"`would change filename.002 to filename.003.

Finally, the unshuffle mechanism relies on a string of space-separated numeric arguments that matches the list printed by the `shuffle` mechanism. It's reaaly just more of the same, but unchecked so providing duplicate or insufficient numbers will no doubt cause a mess. Build a table like the above from the parameters and call the
`:shuffleren` routine to change the numbers back.

Of course, you should test the routine in a dummy area - don't apply it directly to live files.

Since the `random` function is seeded from the time, I've attempted to apply some variability by adding into the number-choosing mechanism a number that may be specified on the command line, hence
0 or 1 numeric arguments - if one numeric argument is provided, that argument is added to the random number so you can have a little bit of variation if you happen to run the routine at the same time on two days.

---- revision

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sourcedir=c:\testso"

set "filename=%1"
:: clear any variables starting #
for /f "tokens=1delims==" %%e in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%e="

:: number of files
set /a #files=50
set /a #files1k=1000+#files
:: length of code to generate
set /a #lencode=10

set "parm= %* "
set /a #count=0
set /a #randomadd=0
set /a #assigned=0
call :readparms %parm%

:: if 0 or 1 parameter, shuffle randomly
if %#count% gtr 2 goto extendkey

:shuffle
set "#shuffle=y"
for /L %%e in (1,1,%#files%) do set "#%%e="
set "#report="
set /a #assigned=0
: nextrandom
call :assignrandom
if %#assigned% lss %#lencode% goto nextrandom
set "#key=%#report%"
:: Extend the key currently in #Report
:extendkey
set /a #accum=1
:nextmore
call :addmore %#report%
if %#assigned% equ %#files% goto donerandom
if %#accum% neq 10 goto nextmore
:: attempt to assign all unassigned
for /L %%e in (%#files,-1,1) do (
 set /a #choice=%%e-1
 call :addreport
)
if %#assigned% neq %#files% if defined #shuffle goto shuffle
if %#assigned% neq %#files% echo Fail&goto :eof
:donerandom
if defined #shuffle echo key is %#key%
: now build rename-list
for /L %%e in (1000,1,%#files1k%) do set "#%%e="
set /a #position=1000
:brlloop
set /a #position+=1
set /a #value=%#report% 2>nul
set /a #value+=1000
if defined #shuffle (set /a #%#position%=#value
 ) else set /a #%#value%=#position
set "#report=%#report:* =%"
if defined #report goto brlloop
:shuffleren
for /L %%e in (1001,1,%#files1k%) do (
 set "#oldname=%%e"
 set "#newname=!#%%e!"
 ren "%sourcedir%\%filename%*.!#oldname:~-3!" "%filename%*.!#oldname:~-3!.!#newname:~-3!.t"
)
for %%b in ("%sourcedir%\%filename%*.t") do ren "%%b" "%%~nb"
goto :eof

:readparms
shift
set "#choice=%1"
if not defined #choice goto :eof
set "#choice=9%1"
for /L %%e in (0,1,9) do set "#choice=!#choice:%%e=!"
if defined #choice echo ignored "%1" &goto readparms
set /a #randomadd=%1
set /a #count+=1
set /a #choice=%1-1
call :addreport

goto readparms

:: Assign a new random number to #report

:assignrandom
set /a #choice=%random%+#randomadd
:: Caution - flow-through

:: Add and count an entry into #report
:: don't add if #choice is already in #report or #assigned

:addreport
set /a #choice=(#choice %% #files) + 1
set /a #assigned+=1
for %%y in (%#assigned% %#report%) do if %#choice%==%%y set /a #assigned-=1&goto :eof
set "#report=%#report%%#choice% "
goto :eof

:: Add some more numbers derived from the existing list

:addmore
set /a #accum+=1
:movel
if "%1"=="" goto :eof
set /a #choice=0
for /L %%y in (1,1,%#accum%) do  call set /a #choice=#choice+%%%%y 2>nul
call :addreport
shift
goto movel
```

This code limits the "key" to #lencode.

First step is to process the parameters provided, but this time build each parameter into #report (the name is a hangover from earlier processing)

If there are fewer than 2 parameters provided, then this is a suffle operation and `#shuffle` is set. In this case, #lencode random numbers are added to a new #report. If `#shuffle` is not set, then the key has been provided in the command line and has been assigned to #report.

Using `#report` as a basis, a specific function is applied, adding new numbers. This means that the result in #report will be identical for the two cases (shuffling or unshuffling) All that is needed then is to add 1000 to the numbers for substringing purposes and build the #1xxx array; either for shuffling or unshuffling; then run the renaming code as before.

If an incorrect code is supplied, then the unshuffling will cause chaos. The file renaming trace-for-verification system survives from the earlier code.

-- another revision

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sourcedir=c:\testso"

set "filename=%1"
:: clear any variables starting #
for /f "tokens=1delims==" %%e in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%e="

:: number of files
set /a #files=50
set /a #files1k=1000+#files
:: length of code to generate
set /a #lencode=10
set "parm= %* "

:: Set flag #shuffle

for %%e in (shuffle) do (
 if "!parm!" neq "!parm:/%%e=!" set "#%%e=Y"&set "parm=!parm:/%%e=!"
)

set /a #count=0
set /a #randomadd=0
set /a #assigned=0
call :readparms %parm%

:: if 0 or 1 parameter, shuffle randomly
if %#count% gtr 2 goto extendkey

:shuffle
set "#shuffle=y"
for /L %%e in (1,1,%#files%) do set "#%%e="
set "#report="
set /a #assigned=0
: nextrandom
call :assignrandom
if %#assigned% lss %#lencode% goto nextrandom
set "#key=%#report%"
:: Extend the key currently in #Report
:extendkey
set /a #accum=1
:nextmore
call :addmore %#report%
if %#assigned% equ %#files% goto donerandom
if %#accum% neq 10 goto nextmore
:: attempt to assign all unassigned
for /L %%e in (%#files,-1,1) do (
 set /a #choice=%%e-1
 call :addreport
)
if %#assigned% neq %#files% if defined #shuffle goto shuffle
if %#assigned% neq %#files% echo Fail&goto :eof
:donerandom
if defined #shuffle if defined #key echo key is %#key%
: now build rename-list
for /L %%e in (1000,1,%#files1k%) do set "#%%e="
set /a #position=1000
:brlloop
set /a #position+=1
set /a #value=%#report% 2>nul
set /a #value+=1000
if defined #shuffle (set /a #%#position%=#value
 ) else set /a #%#value%=#position
set "#report=%#report:* =%"
if defined #report goto brlloop
:shuffleren
for /L %%e in (1001,1,%#files1k%) do (
 set "#oldname=%%e"
 set "#newname=!#%%e!"
 ren "%sourcedir%\%filename%*.!#oldname:~-3!" "%filename%*.!#oldname:~-3!.!#newname:~-3!.t"
)
for %%b in ("%sourcedir%\%filename%*.t") do ren "%%b" "%%~nb"
goto :eof

:readparms
shift
set "#choice=%1"
if not defined #choice goto :eof
set "#choice=9%1"
for /L %%e in (0,1,9) do set "#choice=!#choice:%%e=!"
if defined #choice echo ignored "%1" &goto readparms
set /a #randomadd=%1
set /a #count+=1
set /a #choice=%1-1
call :addreport

goto readparms

:: Assign a new random number to #report

:assignrandom
set /a #choice=%random%+#randomadd
:: Caution - flow-through

:: Add and count an entry into #report
:: don't add if #choice is already in #report or #assigned

:addreport
set /a #choice=(#choice %% #files) + 1
set /a #assigned+=1
for %%y in (%#assigned% %#report%) do if %#choice%==%%y set /a #assigned-=1&goto :eof
set "#report=%#report%%#choice% "
goto :eof

:: Add some more numbers derived from the existing list

:addmore
set /a #accum+=1
:movel
if "%1"=="" goto :eof
set /a #choice=0
for /L %%y in (1,1,%#accum%) do  call set /a #choice=#choice+%%%%y 2>nul
call :addreport
shift
goto movel
```

This time, you need to add a switch `/shuffle` if you are providing a key and wish to shuffle. Without the `/shuffle` switch, specifying fewer than 2 numeric arguments will shuffle randomly, more than 2, unshuffle.

Note that `#key` will only be established for a random shuffle, so that is the only time it's reported (otherwise, the key was provided or it's unshuffling).

Comment: Thanks @Magoo this is very impressive code.  I tested it on 49 files and it works well.  Unfortunately, it requires that I store 49 numbers as the unshuffle code (which is a long 'password') and I would also need to store multiple sets of 49 unshuffle numbers for each file that I shuffle.  Is there any way to input 10 numbers to shuffle and use the same 10 numbers to unshuffle?  I guess doing so would negate the random function.

Comment: Thanks again @Magoo for the revision. This shortens the key to 10 numbers which is better than 49. I can't seem to get it to unshuffle in the correct order though even when entering the 10 number key generated by shuffling and when unshuffling it still outputs "key is:" 10 numbers (different from the input key). As an additional feature more in line with my ideal end goal, is there any way to modify it so that it will allow me to input 10 numbers as a shuffle key, and also use them to unshuffle? I will want to shuffle many files and will want to use the same key to shuffle them. Thanks again!

Comment: If you start with **thisbatch name** or **thisbatch name anumber**, then the routine should generate `key is asequenceofnumbers`. If you then execute **thisbatch name asequenceofnumbers**, it should restore the original order of name.001..name.049. The sequence of numbers must be space-separated. The filename must be a single string of characters, not a "quoted string with spaces". Works for me...I can't see what you're entering, and of course the shuffling is randomised, so it's not reproducible.

Comment: Hi @Magoo Yes, that's what I'm doing, doesn't seem to work for me (unshuffling).  I noticed the line `set "parm= %* "` in the "::number of files" section is missing in the revised code, but present in the original code, could it be the sequence of numbers aren't being passed into the batch file?  When I add that line back in, it seems to work, but still won't unshuffle when I enter the sequence of numbers.  I'm also on Windows Vista, are there any new commands or variables you're using in the revised version that requires a newer version of Windows?  I will test on a Win 11 machine & post back

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what it would be. I'm using a standby machine at present and I seem to have been overenthusiastic with removing some code that I'd included to control testing.

Comment: Using the corrected revised code, if I enter `shuf.bat Remy-B.mov` it generates a key. If I use that key `shuf.bat Remy-B.mov 12 32 34 44 9 7 20 1 18 13` it unshuffles correctly: `Remy-B.mov.001.008.001
Remy-B.mov.002.024.002
Remy-B.mov.003.048.003` but if I start fresh with the original files and try to shuffle using  `shuf.bat Remy-B.mov 12 32 34 44 9 7 20 1 18 13`  and then repeat the same to unshuffle, the files are just reshuffled, not unshuffled: `Remy-B.mov.001.008.043
Remy-B.mov.002.024.033
Remy-B.mov.003.048.035`

Comment: Thanks so much @Magoo for the additional revision which allows me to enter my own 10 digit key.  Just wondering, what is the highest number I can enter in the key?  Sometimes when I put 49 or 50 as a number it doesn't like it, but if I shift those same numbers into different positions it will work.  And if I wanted to start with file 000 and go to file 049 instead (still 50 files), would that be easy for me to change in the code?  Your expertise, time and effort is much appreciated! :)  Is there a way for me to send you a donation in appreciation? You've written a whole program here :)

Comment: I've tried many numbers - 1 to 3 digits. I'm sure it doesn't like 0, but it seems to work, even with repeated numbers. If after `:shuffleren`, you change `set /a "#oldname=%%e"` to `set /a #oldname=%%e-1` and similarly subtract 1 from `#newname` on the next line, then the routine should handle .000 also. The processing works by taking a short sequence of numbers and extending that sequence by applying a constant function to it. No doubt there are resultant combinations that won't then comply with the `change all filenames` requirement.

Comment: Donation? streng verboten by SO TOS. OTOH, visiting `www.kiva.org` isn't, and I don't profit by that...

Comment: Thanks @Magoo I was wondering, if I use `shuf.bat filename 3` and it generates a key, would I still have to put that `3` in front of the key to unshuffle?

Comment: No. That number is used only to modify the random seed slightly. The key presented is the key.

Comment: I see.  But you can still use the single digit in addition to entering 10 numbers as the key to shuffle? e.g. `shuf.bat filename 3 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Comment: No. it's only used to modify the random-number generation in the random-shuffle operation. If 0 or 1 numeric parameters are supplied, a random-shuffle is performed; if a numeric parameter is supplied, it modifies the random-number. If `#lencode` numbers are supplied together with `/shuffle` then those numbers form the key.  If `#lencode` numbers are supplied without `/shuffle` then the files will be unshuffled.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. However, I "half-understood" the part with 9 files, so here it is my partial solution.

This is **shuffle.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "basefile=%1"
set "i=0"
md "renamed"

:loop
shift
if "%1" equ "" goto endLoop

set /A i+=1
move %basefile%.00%i% renamed\%basefile%.00%1 > NUL
goto loop

:endLoop
move renamed\*.* . > NUL
rd renamed
```

I started with this set of files that have the same number of characters of their names, so we can always identify them (even with the names changed):

```
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 1 testfile.exe.001
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 2 testfile.exe.002
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 3 testfile.exe.003
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 4 testfile.exe.004
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 5 testfile.exe.005
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 6 testfile.exe.006
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 7 testfile.exe.007
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 8 testfile.exe.008
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 9 testfile.exe.009
```

After this command is executed:

```
shuffle.bat testfile.exe 8 5 2 9 4 1 3 7 6
```

... you get these files:

```
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 6 testfile.exe.001
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 3 testfile.exe.002
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 7 testfile.exe.003
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 5 testfile.exe.004
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 2 testfile.exe.005
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 9 testfile.exe.006
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 8 testfile.exe.007
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 1 testfile.exe.008
09/09/2022  09:36 a. m.                 4 testfile.exe.009
```

That is, the first file go to position 8, the second file to position 5, etc. until the ninth file in position 6. Good!

Now, this is **unshuffle.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "basefile=%1"
set "i=0"
md "renamed"

:loop
shift
if "%1" equ "" goto endLoop

set /A i+=1
move %basefile%.00%1 renamed\%basefile%.00%i% > NUL
goto loop

:endLoop
move renamed\*.* . > NUL
rd renamed
```

So after this command is executed:

```
unshuffle.bat testfile.exe 8 5 2 9 4 1 3 7 6
```

... the files recover their original positions!  **:)**

Whats next?

---

**New method added**

I read again the question, particularly the *"I could do the same with files .011 - .019, then with files .021 - 0.29, etc."* part and I think I have a complete solution now.

I didn't created two .bat files for shuffle/unshuffle operations. Instead, I added the **/U** switch as the first parameter of the only batch file to select the "unshuffle" task.

I used two different shuffle methods for each group of ten files. Files in 001..009, 021..029 and 041..049 (even) groups use the original method, and files in 011..019 and 031..039 (odd) groups use the "opposite" method. The files 010, 020, 030, 040 and 050 are *not* renamed.

This is the new **shuffle.bat**:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "unshuffle="
if /I "%1" equ "/U" set "unshuffle=1" & shift

set "basefile=%1"
set "i=0"
md renamed

:loop
shift
if "%1" equ "" goto endLoop

set /A i+=1
set "flipFlop="
(for /L %%j in (0,1,4) do (
   if not defined flipFlop (
      if not defined unshuffle (
         move %basefile%.0%%j%i% renamed\%basefile%.0%%j%1
      ) else (
         move %basefile%.0%%j%1 renamed\%basefile%.0%%j%i%
      )
      set "flipFlop=1"
   ) else (
      if not defined unshuffle (
         move %basefile%.0%%j%1 renamed\%basefile%.0%%j%i%
      ) else (
         move %basefile%.0%%j%i% renamed\%basefile%.0%%j%1
      )
      set "flipFlop="
   )
)) > NUL
goto loop

:endLoop
echo These files were not renamed:
echo/
dir %basefile%.*
move renamed\*.* . > NUL
rd renamed
```

After this command:

```
shuffle.bat testfile.exe 8 5 2 9 4 1 3 7 6
```

... the resulting files are these:

```
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 6 testfile.exe.001
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 3 testfile.exe.002
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 7 testfile.exe.003
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 5 testfile.exe.004
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 2 testfile.exe.005
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 9 testfile.exe.006
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 8 testfile.exe.007
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 1 testfile.exe.008
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                 4 testfile.exe.009
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                10 testfile.exe.010
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                18 testfile.exe.011
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                15 testfile.exe.012
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                12 testfile.exe.013
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                19 testfile.exe.014
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                14 testfile.exe.015
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                11 testfile.exe.016
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                13 testfile.exe.017
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                17 testfile.exe.018
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                16 testfile.exe.019
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                20 testfile.exe.020
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                26 testfile.exe.021

. . .

09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                44 testfile.exe.049
09/09/2022  11:46 a. m.                50 testfile.exe.050
```

After this command:

```
shuffle.bat /U testfile.exe 8 5 2 9 4 1 3 7 6
```

files recover their original positions.

Comment: Thank you @Aacini  This is very elegant code.   I like your use of the "opposite" method for the odd numbered sets of 10 (i.e. 011..019, 031..039).  I noticed you ran into the same problem I did (conceptually) with files 010, 020, 030m 040 and 050.  If the variables input were ten numbers including a "0", would this allow those to be shuffled as well?  Of course this would have the problem of the non-existent .000 file.

Comment: Is there any way to shuffle the files more broadly? (e.g. to allow any file to be shuffled into any position? like 005 becoming 045 and so on?)  I thought of adding another set of 5 variables to the command line such as "4 2 0 1 3" in front of the "8 5 2 9 4 1 3 7 6" to allow shuffling across all files.  Would that work?  Or is there a way to internalize this in the batch file?  However adding these numbers as external variables allows for more customization to the shuffling pattern.  It just means entering more variables unfortunately.

Comment: I just conceived of an idea to be able to internalize the "4 2 0 1 3" sequence I proposed in my previous comment ( to allow shuffling across all files) into the batch file.  Could the sequence be derived from the "8 5 2 9 4 1 3 7 6"  set?  For example "if %1 is 1 or 2, set to 4", "if/elseif %2 is 3 or 4 set to 2", "if/elseif" %3 is 5 or 6 set to 0" or something like that?  Just a raw thought.

Comment: I updated my post to indicate that the one file I don't want shuffled is file 050.  It should remain file 050.